# How to return a webpage containing images using spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am just getting started with spring and have used their spring initialiser to create a project. I then tweaked the java code to get it do what I wanted:

[image: File for launching web app]

[image: This code maps a certain path to this method]

The above method maps a GET request to the location "/hello/{name" to the method I have written which returns a string: 'Hello {name}". I want an image to be returned next to this; how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a common recommended approach. But since your question is to serve and HTML page with image via HTTP API, a very basic example is given below. Here the first API uses the second one internally to server the image. The image is served from resources folder and expecting that there is an image available with given name.
Note that you need to use proper *MediaType* for response *Content-Type*

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/hello/{name}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
       return "<html>\n" + "<header><title>Hello "+name+"</title></header>\n" +
            "<body>\n" + "Hello \n" +name+ "<img src='http://localhost:8080/image?name="+name+"'/></body>\n" + "</html>";
    }
@GetMapping(
        value = "/image",
        produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFile(@RequestParam(value = "name") final String name) throws IOException {
    //Get Image using name
    var image= new ClassPathResource(name+".png");
    return  ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG).body(new InputStreamResource(image.getInputStream()));
}
}
```

Now you can access this even via browser pointing to *http://<host:port/hello/{name}*. This will display the HTML page with the image.

If you want to get image via API, then you need to get the resource and return *MediaType* *IMAGE_PNG_VALUE* (If the image is PNG file).
Example:

```
 @GetMapping(
        value = "/image",
        produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFile(@RequestParam(value = "name") final String name) throws IOException {
    //Get Image using name
    var image= new ClassPathResource(name+".png");
    return  ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG).body(new InputStreamResource(image.getInputStream()));
}
```